# Erro ao usar LIKE pra fazer pesquisa por nome

Tags: java, sql, javafx

Quando eu usava Mysql eu conseguia usar o `LIKE ?` pra fazer pesquisas por nome, codigo, etc... Agora no SQL Server não estou conseguindo.

Tenho um TextField e um botão pesquisar, quero pega o valor do textField e passar para a pesquisa. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT\n"
                + " Contrato.AutoId                         AS                Contrato_ID,\n"
                + " Contrato.Codigo                         AS                Codigo_contrato,\n"
                + " Pessoa.Nome                             AS                Contratante,\n"
                + " SuspensaoVinculo.VinculoRescindido      AS                Vinculo_rescindido,\n"
                + " SuspensaoVinculo.DataSuspensao          AS                Data_suspencao,\n"
                + " SuspensaoVinculo.DataReativacao         AS                Data_reativacao ");
        sql.append("FROM Contrato                           WITH (NOLOCK)\n"
                + " INNER JOIN Pessoa                       WITH(NOLOCK) ON Contrato.Contratante = Pessoa.AutoId\n"
                + " LEFT JOIN SuspensaoVinculo              WITH(NOLOCK) ON SuspensaoVinculo.Contrato = Contrato.AutoId ");
        sql.append("WHERE\n"
                + " Pessoa.Tipo             =   2 "
                + "     Pessoa.Nome LIKE ? ");
        sql.append("ORDER BY Pessoa.Nome ");

        /* Abre a conexão */
        Connection conn = Conexao.abrir();

        /* Mapeamento objeto relacional */
        PreparedStatement comando = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setString(1, "%" + c.getContratante() + "%"); 
        ....
```

E na minha view recupero dessa forma:

```
private void atualizarInicial() {
        Cadastros cadastros = new Cadastros();
        ConsultaCadastro consulta = new ConsultaCadastro();
        List<Cadastros> lista;
        try {
            cadastros.setContratante(pesquisar.getText());
            lista = consulta.buscar(cadastros);
            tblCadastros.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista));
            ...
```

Essa é a exceção:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Contrato'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está faltando um AND

```
"WHERE\n"
+ " Pessoa.Tipo             =   2 **AND**"
+ "     Pessoa.Nome LIKE ? ");
```

Comment: Nossa verdade, esqueci do AND e tava me matando kk. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Verifique nesta parte a falta de um "AND" (ou outro operador) que talvez seja a origem do seu erro:

```
sql.append("WHERE\n" 
           + " Pessoa.Tipo             =   2"
           + "  AND   Pessoa.Nome LIKE ? ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Além do AND depois do Pessoa.tipo tente acrescentar aspas simples no LIKE, o SQL usa assim:

```
comando.setString(1, "'%" + c.getContratante() + "%'");
```